# Testing for stationarity of many time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a series of data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kk2zj67u9f31oq/returns.txt). Now `pd` is an identifier that distinguishes between different elements (there are 2228 unique elements), `Date` is the date and `excess` is just a column of values. I want to test for stationarity of `excess` for each `pd` using `Box.test`, `adf.test`, and `kpss.test` within the `fpp` package. To illustrate what I mean, take `pd` = 1 as an example:

```
library(fpp)

pd1 <- read.delim("E:/something/something/pd1.txt") # Here I just extracted only the corresponding values for pd = 1 from the data file #

excessret <- matrix(0,dim(pd1),1)

excessret[,1] <- pd1[,3]

Box.test(excessret[,1], lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")

adf.test(excessret[,1], alternative="stationary")

kpss.test(excessret[,1])
```

The results of each of the three tests are, respectively:

```
Box-Ljung test

data:  excessret[, 1]
X-squared = 47.7202, df = 20, p-value = 0.0004656    


Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  excessret[, 1]
Dickey-Fuller = -3.2127, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.09056
alternative hypothesis: stationary


KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  excessret[, 1]
KPSS Level = 0.1942, Truncation lag parameter = 2, p-value = 0.1
```

Say I set a significance level of 5%. Then the rules are:

1) For the `Box.test`, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

2) For the `adf.test`, if p-value < 0.05 => stationary

3) For the `kpss.test`, if p-value > 0.05 => stationary (note change of inequality)

So in this case, the `Box.test` and `kpss.test` suggest pd = 1 is stationary while the `adf.test` suggests pd = 1 is non stationary.

My question is, I wish to do this for every single `pd`, then count how many `pd`'s are stationary, for all three tests. So for example, using the `Box.test`, I wish to apply `Box.test` on every `pd` and then see out of the 2228 unique elements, how many are classified as stationary. Then repeat this for the other two tests.

Thanks.

Comment: since when is the Ljung-Box test a test for stationarity? I am honestly asking because you are not the first person to say that, and I am wondering if its true.

Comment: @Paul http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222765/can-we-use-box-ljung-as-a-stationarity-test-for-time-series

Comment: I actually put an answer on the question you linked (though it hasn't been upvoted at all). My point is that the LB test is a stronger condition of white noise, and therefore will miss many time series that are stationary but not white noise. Such as strongly mean reverting time series in the limit of large times (like many OU processes or AR processes). These will fail the LB test but are still stationary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this for example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(returns)
DT[,Date := as.Date(Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')]
library(fpp)
library(xts)
DT[,{ x = xts(excess,Date)
      list(box= Box.test(x)$p.value <0.05 ,
           adf= adf.test(x)$p.value <0.05 ,
           kpss= kpss.test(x)$p.value >0.05)
},pd]

         pd   box  adf  kpss
   1:     1  TRUE TRUE FALSE
   2:    21  TRUE TRUE FALSE
   3:    26  TRUE TRUE FALSE
   4:    29  TRUE TRUE FALSE
   5:    31 FALSE TRUE FALSE
  ---                       
2224: 82840  TRUE TRUE FALSE
2225: 82848 FALSE TRUE FALSE
2226: 82850  TRUE TRUE FALSE
2227: 83053 FALSE TRUE FALSE
2228: 83273  TRUE TRUE FALSE
```